# Configure opentelemetry to create spans with Spring boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, newrelic, open-telemetry

I am trying to create `spans` for my `newRelic` using `micrometer` with `spring boot 3` application

My code looks something like this -

```
import io.micrometer.tracing.annotation.NewSpan; 
import io.micrometer.tracing.Tracer;

@Autowired
private Tracer tracer;

@NewSpan("span") public Person apply(Message<Person> person){ 
var span= tracer.spanBuilder().name("event").start(); 
span.end();    
}
```

My dependency tree looks like this -

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2022.0.4</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.9</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

    <!--        TRACE       -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.micrometer/micrometer-registry-new-relic -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-registry-new-relic</artifactId>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

and I have the application properties like this -

```
 management:
  tracing:
   sampling:
    probability: 1.0
  newrelic:
   metrics:
    export:
     enabled: true
     api-key: sss
     account-id: sss
  endpoints:
   web:
    exposure:
    include: "*"
```

I have no logs anywhere, the code executes fine, but I am not able to see any spans in my newRelic.

Can someone point out the shortcomings of this setup ?

I am able to see the traceId and spanId in my logs though

> 2023-12-04T10:40:20.529Z  INFO
> [event-relay,event-relay-8657d79975-xqdg8,bad941449fc11d712c78db4bc0cad8d5,03f15d59cea9ff0c]
> 1 --- [   scheduling-1] c.eventrelay.Producer     : sending event
> against ff201146-94b1-435f-a846-57ac76449f11

where `bad941449fc11d712c78db4bc0cad8d5` is my `traceId` and `03f15d59cea9ff0c` is my `spanId`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74770600/newspan-and-continuespan-support-in-spring-boot-3

Answer (score 0):

I used `opentelemetry` to export my spans.

`io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-exporter-otlp` as described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.micrometer-tracing.tracer-implementations.otel-otlp) solved my problem.

I am also using this property to export:

> ```
> management:   
>     otlp:
>       tracing:
>           endpoint: https://localhost:4318/v1/traces
>           headers:
>              api-key: shdgjsgdjdjgajdjasgd
>              account-id: abc
> ```